# React Native personalized native ads

Tags: react-native, admob, ads, native-ads

what needs to be done to see personalized ads using admob? I've created native ads using react-native-admob-native-ads. Can you tell me when personalized ads start working? Do i need to add my app to google store? Do i need to obtain consent with the User Messaging Platform? I've found smthing like that https://medium.com/ulangi-app/how-to-implement-google-consent-form-sdk-for-admob-in-react-native-apps-7538656926cd.